# How to play opus decoded frame, or split 1-byte pcm16 to 2-bytes pcm(bitDepthInBytes)?

Tags: go, audio, audio-streaming, opus

when recording the microphone, the recorded chunks was raw PCM8 format and I was able to send it and play it by changing bitDepthInBytes = 2 without any noise, but when I've sent encoded opus frames through a network and decode them to PCM16, I couldn't play them unless I convert them to PCM8 but it was noisy. Here is my code:

```
const sampleRate = 48000
const channels = 1
....
....

    dec, err := opus.NewDecoder(sampleRate, channels)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var frameSizeMs float32 = 20
    frameSize := int(channels * frameSizeMs * sampleRate / 1000)
    pcm := make([]int16, frameSize)

    // (sampleRate int, channelNum int, bitDepthInBytes int, bufferSizeInBytes int)
    context, err := oto.NewContext(sampleRate, channels, 1, frameSize*2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    player := context.NewPlayer()

    ...
    ...

    _, err := dec.Decode(data, pcm)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var mask uint16 = 0x8000


    pcm8 := make([]byte, frameSize)
    for i := 0; i < frameSize; i++ {
        // using this work and play sound but it has noise
        pcm8[i] = byte((uint16(pcm[i]) ^ mask) >> 8)

    }
    
    _, _ = player.Write(pcm8)
```

Comment: 8-bit PCM... wow, why?  Your PCM bit depth has no meaning in the context of Opus anyway... why not start with 16-bit PCM?  Anyway, you really want to avoid truncating when going down in bit depth.  Dithering is much better.  Even if you were to truncate though, I'm not confident in that bitmask you've set up.  Surely, you wanted `0xFF00`?  Also, are you confident of endianness here?  (Forgive me, I don't use Go, so I'm not sure how it's representing 16-bit integers in the language... whether it's system-native or not.)

Comment: I solved it thanks, I've sent encoded opus frames frame of my smartphone microphone and I was able to decode them, but I couldn't play them, and the player I've used, only support to write <byte[]> and the decoded frames were <int16[]>, so I've needed it to format the data before writing it to the player
`audioBytes[i*2] = (byte) buffer[i];`
`audioBytes[i*2 + 1] = (byte)((int)buffer[i] >> 8 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading this, I was able to know how to format your PCM buffer to playable audio bytes https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/adonax/audiocue/AudioCue.java, this the snippet I've used:

```
public static byte[] fromBufferToAudioBytes(byte[] audioBytes, float[] buffer)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = buffer.length; i < n; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] *= 32767;
        
        audioBytes[i*2] = (byte) buffer[i];
        audioBytes[i*2 + 1] = (byte)((int)buffer[i] >> 8 );
    }
    
    return audioBytes;
}
```

And this is what I've updated in my code

```
    pcm8 := make([]byte, frameSize * 2)
    for i := 0; i < frameSize; i++ {
        //pcm[i] *= 32767 // uncomment when pcm array is float insteand of int16
        pcm8[i*2] =  byte(uint16(pcm[i]))
        pcm8[i*2 + 1] = byte(uint16(pcm[i]) >> 8)
    }
```